# react set iframe src from button click

Tags: reactjs, react-admin

Trying to set a button or toggle switch that will alter end of the url to "light" or "dark" and refresh the iframe

```js
const url = ("http://localhost/ij3&theme=")
const mode = ['light', 'dark']

const TestPage = () => (
    <Card>
        <Switch defaultChecked />
        <Button
            onClick={() => { }}
            label="dark">
        </Button>
        <IframeResizer
            src={url + mode}
            style={{ width: '1px', width: '100%'}}
        />
    </Card>
);

export default TestPage;
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

make `mode` as state in react so whenever it will change, on re-render it will also update the iframe src

Comment: thanks thats what i was looking for, just did it as


const url = ("http://localhost/ij3&theme=")

class TestPage extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
     this.state = {mode: "dark"};
      }
      changeTheme = () => {
        var newMode = this.state.mode == 'dark' ? 'light' : 'dark';
          this.setState({mode: newMode} );

render() {
return (
<Card>
      <Switch defaultChecked onClick={this.changeTheme}/>
<IframeResizer
 src={url + this.state.mode}
  style={{ width: '1px', width: '100%'}}
/>
</Card>
);
export default TestPage;

Comment: Can you mark answer as accepted as it could also help others.